# How to create all variations of a 20 featured categorical data with python?

Tags: python, data-generation

I am trying to create training data. I will label them later. My data set should look like

Data_Format_For_One_Item: ID|Feature 1| Feature 2| .... | Feature N.

All features are either categorical or integer in a predefined range (like 1-5 similar to categorical). Is there an easy way of creating all variations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to generate such a dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
       
n_rows = 500
n_cols= 20
range_start = 1
range_end = 5
dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(range_start, range_end+1,size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col_'+str(idx+1) for idx in range(n_cols)])
```

Demo output

[image]